# Can you connect to a MySQL database on Linux through windows

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, linux

I want to connect to a MySQL database that is installed on a linux box. The machine I will use to connect to MySQL will be windows. So, is it possible to connect to a MySQL database that is installed on linux through a windows machine. I will be using ASP.NET C# to make the connection. Is this possible?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/  Just remember to enable TCP support in MySQL. It generally defaults to off in most standard installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to give it the server name that the MYSQL database is on and use an odbc connection.

Comment: ..and ODBC isn't even necessary.  You can connect directly to the server using any client library.